# How to handle different messages in RAISERROR?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have to RAISERRORS at different positions with different messages.

i.e.

```
Begin Try
      if(Convert(time,@OpeningTime) < convert(time,@ExpiryTime))
      Begin;
            Raiserror('Opening time cannot be smaller than expiry time', 16,10);

      End


          Declare @Days int
          Set @Days= (Select Days from Days where IsActive=1)

          declare @Message varchar(100)
          Set @Message= 'The difference between current date and expiry date must be equal or greater than '+ Convert(varchar,@Days)

          if(datediff(dd, @ExpiryDate, GETDATE()) > @Days)
          Begin
                Raiserror(@Message, 16,10);

          End

End Try

Begin Catch
       Raiserror('Opening time cannot be smaller than expiry time', 16,10);
End Catch
```

Now the problem is that in each case I have to return different message in catch block, not the static text such as it should display the error that I have raised

Answer (score 1):

Use `ERROR_MESSAGE()` function instead

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-message-transact-sql

Result :

```
Begin Catch
       Raiserror(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 16,10);
End Catch
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `THROW;` in your catch block to re-throw the raised error:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```